# cannot initialize return object of type 'Shape Shape::*' with an lvalue of type 'Shape *'

Tags: c++, pointers, object, inheritance

Is the problem that the static function is expecting a return type of `Shape Shape::*`?? and is getting one that's just `Shape*`.

```
static Shape Shape::*makeShape(char ch,int posx,int posy){

    Shape *rp = new O(posx, posy);
    return rp;
}

O::O(int posx, int posy){
    x = &posx;
    y = &posy;
}
```

Comment: Watch where you put that asterisk, you're supposed to return a pointer to `Shape` (i.e. `Shape*`).

Comment: You have a much worse problem once you get the code to build though, as you in the `O` constructor store pointers to local variables. The arguments will go out of scope and disappear once the constructor function returns, leaving you with pointers to non-existing data. *Why* are you using pointers? There in the `O` constructor (seems like a bad name to me as well) returning from the factory function `makeShape`?

Comment: Your analysis of the compilation error is right on the money, and is absolutely correct. The expected return value here is a pointer to a member of the class called `Shape` whose type is also `Shape`. That is a logical fallacy, since a class cannot contain itself. If it were possible to do so, the entire universe would get swallowed into a supermassive black hole, with a resulting sub-atomic explosion of every particle, at a speed of light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// return type (marked with v)
//     vvvvv        v
static Shape Shape::*makeShape
//           ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^
// function name (marked with ^)
```

You seem to have mixed up your return type and the name of your function.

What you meant is probably

```
static Shape *Shape::makeShape(...)
```